# Getting `Error: invalid BigNumber value` when trying to perform a swap with swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to build Node.js application that will swap tokens through the router contract of Uniswap-like dex (it is called Ubeswap, a fork of the Uniswapv2 on Celo).

I have tried multiple approaches and nothing works for me so far.

Here is the code of the function I have build:

```
const {
    ChainId,
    Fetcher, 
    CELO,
    Route,
    TradeType,
    Trade,
    TokenAmount,
    Token,
    Percent
} = require ('@ubeswap/sdk')
const ethers = require('ethers')
const fs = require('fs')
const Web3 = require('web3')



// chaing config
const chainId = ChainId.ALFAJORES.toString()
const fornoUrl = 'https://alfajores-forno.celo-testnet.org'
const customHttpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(fornoUrl)
const web3 = new Web3(fornoUrl);

//wallet config
const targetAccount = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('path to the file with private key', 'utf-8'))
const privateKey = Buffer.from(targetAccount.privateKey, 'hex')
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)
const account = signer.connect(customHttpProvider)


customHttpProvider.getBlockNumber().then((result) => {
    console.log("Current block number: " + result);
  });

// token for tokens we are interested in
const celoAddressAlfa = '0xF194afDf50B03e69Bd7D057c1Aa9e10c9954E4C9'
const cusdAddressAlfa = '0x874069Fa1Eb16D44d622F2e0Ca25eeA172369bC1'


const UniswapV2RouterAddress = '0xE3D8bd6Aed4F159bc8000a9cD47CffDb95F96121'
const UniswapV2RouterABI = [abi removed to save space]
const UniswapV2RouterContract = new ethers.Contract(UniswapV2RouterAddress, UniswapV2RouterABI, account)


    const init = async () => {
    //get data about tokens and pairs
    const token1 = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, cusdAddressAlfa, customHttpProvider)
    const token2 = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, celoAddressAlfa, customHttpProvider)
    const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(token1, token2, customHttpProvider)
    const route = new Route([pair], token1)

    const amountInWei = '100000000000000000' // 1
    const amountInHex = web3.utils.toHex('amountInWei')
    const path = [token1.address, token2.address]
    const amountOut = await UniswapV2RouterContract.getAmountsOut(amountInWei, path)   
    const amountOutMinHex = amountOut[1]._hex   
    const to = UniswapV2RouterAddress
    const deadline = Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10

    const tx = await UniswapV2RouterContract.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountInHex,
        amountOutMinHex,
        path,
        to,
        deadline    
    )

    const receipt = await tx.await()

    console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`)
    console.log(`Transaction was mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`)
}

init()
```

When I try to run it, it throws an error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)`

when trying to execute the

`UniswapV2RouterContract.swapExactTokensForTokens`

I can't figure out why. As I understand it, I need to provide the values in hex, so I converted them. I have also tried providing values for `amountIn` and ```amountOut`` in wei and in decimals, and tried wrapping them with string(). Nothing helps. I am always getting exactly the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: My first guess would be a type overflow on one your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, errors like this happen when you pass the wrong data. For examples, you pass a value of type string to a parameter of type uint256
(passing a string to function register(uint256 value) instead of an integer)